# Remove certain value from Google Maps array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google Map that allows users to click anywhere on the map and place a marker. I also have two buttons clear and remove. The code in the clear button looks like this and removes all of the markers:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++) {

            markersArray[i].setMap(null);

    }
```

However the remove needs to remove the last marker placed. My question is how is this possible. I am storing the value markersArray.length further down the page and retrieving it when required through the following:

```
var removemarker = document.getElementsByName('markernum')[0].value;
```

I have tried feeding this value into the loop through the code below however this does not work:

```
            markersArray[removemarker].setMap(null);
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing you're storing the markers in order (last marker added, goes last in the array), I don't think you need to store that value and then retrieve it. If you want to remove the last marker of the array of markers you can do it directly:

```
markersArray[markersArray.length-1].setMap(null);
```

And if that removed element is of not use, you can remove it from the array.

```
markersArray.pop();
```

Comment: Thanks that works (and will suffice) the only issue is it removes the last marker but if they click remove again then it will not remove that marker

Comment: ok, if you are not going to use the removed marker anymore, you can remove it from the array too. See my update. That way, everytime they click the remove button, they will remove one marker: last, next to last and so on.